# Magento 2.3 Minicart check if subtotal is above value

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

I want to check inside my `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/subtotal/totals.html` file if the subtotal is larger than 29.95.

I want to display some additional text if subtotal is larger or smaller than 29.95. The problem is that it is loaded inside a .html file so I cannot use php for this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have following knockout code in html file to achieve your desired result.

```
<!-- ko if: cart().subtotalAmount < 29.95 -->
    <span>custom message if subtotal is less then 29.95</span>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: cart().subtotalAmount > 29.95 -->
    <span>custom message if subtotal is greater then 29.95</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but it does display the message both. So it does not check if the subtotal is greater than 29.95.

Comment: This is something related to static content deploy so after making the change you need to remove var/view_preprocessor/* and pub/static/frontend/* then php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f and finally php bin/magento cache:flush ... To make sure weather ur changes reflected or not try appending some custom text without any conditions ...

Comment: Thanks! I did indeed deploy the static content, but it seems that the if element does not work. I added the code into `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicartsubtotal.html`

Comment: Strange !!! I tested the code and was working for me ... Anyways good luck ...

Comment: It indeed works fine, it was the static folder that did not flush well. Many thanks. But the only thing I face now, is that the best way to implement this, would be to create a new template file, instead of adding it to the `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/subtotal.html` Is there a easy way to add a new file and display this above the subtotal.html file?

Comment: You can override the template file using requirejs-config.js or else you can add the message via custom javascript on runtime ... I think these 2 ways are possible ...

Comment: Any idea what code to use for the file `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html` It seems that it can not check the `cart().subtotalAmount` in that template.

Comment: This should work. totals().subtotal

Comment: Hero of the day, works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Yash Shah's answer worked for me, but only after I found the right place for the code. I added it inside an existing 'ko' element (I'm not familiar with Knockout).

I edited my subtotal.html from this...

```
<div class="subtotal">
    <span class="label">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'Cart Subtotal' --><!-- /ko -->
    </span>

    <!-- ko foreach: elems -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

...to this...

```
<div class="subtotal">
    <span class="label">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'Cart Subtotal' --><!-- /ko -->
    </span>

    <!-- ko foreach: elems -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: cart().subtotalAmount < 50.00 -->
            <span>Message for orders under £50</span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: cart().subtotalAmount > 50.00 -->
            <span>Message for orders over £50</span>
        <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work in Magento 2.

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 1 || getCartParam('summary_count') == 0 -->
<span>items</span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 1 -->
<span>item</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```